# Can't center this Bootstrap div

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Every other div is centered but this one. And it's been driving me nuts for a few hours. I finally broke down and posted. Attached is a pic where you can see it's not centered.

You can see it live [here](http://druvocals.com/dv).

Image of div not centered:

[image: Image of div not centered]

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: both div in center??

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include *the desired behavior*, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you right, you want each testimonial centered in its containing div? How about adding `margin-left: 25%;` to both `.testimonial-section` and `.testimonial-description`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use bootstrap helper classes `.center-block` and `.text-center` to center the content

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="testimonial-section center-block">
         Denim you probably haven't heard of. Lorem ipsum dolor met consectetur adipisicing sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, of them jean shorts sed magna aliqua. Lorem ipsum dolor met.
    </div>
    <div class="testimonial-desc text-center">
        <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=9&amp;txt=100%C3%97100&amp;w=100&amp;h=100" alt="">
        <div class="testimonial-writer">
            <div class="testimonial-writer-name">Zahed Kamal</div>
            <div class="testimonial-writer-designation">Front End Developer</div>
            <a href="#" class="testimonial-writer-company">Touch Base Inc</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the following:

```
.testimonial-section {
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.testimonial-desc {
    text-align: center;
}
```

[image]

Optionally, you can add the following:

```
.testimonial-section:after {
    margin-left: 5px;
}
```

which will make it:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

> .testimonial-section {
>       margin: 0 auto; }

Comment: elaborate your answer. Where should he try?? which file to change?? Give detailed answer.